# заполнить pdf при помощи формы на сайте

Tags: php, pdf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Приветствую! На сайте почты России можно заполнить и распечатать pdf бланк почтового перевода, ссылка https://www.pochta.ru/form?type=F112EP_COD_SINGLE мне нужно, чтобы посетитель ввёл свои данные в форму и после нажатия на кнопку отправить, сформировался заполненный pdf-бланк, который отправится мне на email.

Может есть у кого пример, как данными из формы заполнить поля в шаблоне pdf бланка?

```
<form action="wo_s.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя:">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш телефон/email:">
<input type="image" src="snd.png"></form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){$name=$_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){$email=$_POST['email'];}
if(empty($name)){echo "Не указано имя";echo "<br/><a href=javascript: onclick=document.getElementById('wo').style.display='block';>Вернуться назад</a>";exit;}
if(empty($email)){echo "Не указан email";echo "<br/><a href=javascript: onclick=document.getElementById('wo').style.display='block';>Вернуться назад</a>";exit;}
$to=".....@mail.ru";
$subject="...";
$message="name: $name \nemail: $email";
$headers="content-type:text/plain; charset=windows-1251";
$send=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($send=='true'){echo "Ваша заявка отправлена";}
else{echo "Ошибка";}
?>
```

Comment: самый простой варант - генериурете html, потом перегоняете в pdf с каким нибудь [tag:dompdf]

Comment: Я использовал библиотеки fpdf и fpdi. делал шаблонный pdf, а потом сверху писал и ставил штрих код. Вполне понятное занятие оказалось

Comment: Думаю как вариант можно заполнить готовый pdf бланк данными из формы обратной связи, но для этого нужен скрипт

Comment: @Grasss что именно вызвало у Вас проблему?

Comment: возможно, как вариант, проще будет заполнить шаблонный эксель, и его сохранить в пдф, или сразу его печатать. С именованными ячейками это весьма просто будет.